# Devise + Omniauth - testing - getting no route matches "/oauth/authorize"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to write tests for authentication with Twitter and Facebook. I am using Devise and Omniauth. When I try it out it works correctly, but I can't get the tests to pass for it.

I'm following [instructions](http://blog.codegram.com/2011/2/acceptance-tests-with-cucumber-devise-omniauth-and-twitter), but it isn't in depth enough for me, plus I'm doing things a little differently (already have some code base). I have a custom controllers for omniauth_callbacks and registrations.

My problem is that when I run the tests it says:

```
(::) failed steps (::)

No route matches "/oauth/authorize" (ActionController::RoutingError)
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
(eval):2:in `click_link'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
features/link_twitter.feature:19:in `And I link twitter'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/link_twitter.feature:16 # Scenario: User links twitter
```

Where is this `/oauth/authorize` route coming from and how do I handle that?

It does not look like it is getting to my `OmniauthCallbacksController`. It follows the link and then dies. I think it has to do with Omniauth's call back method during test mode, but I'm not sure how to change / manage that.

**Update**: Here are my routes for Devise.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
    :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", 
    :registrations => 'registrations', 
    :passwords => 'passwords', 
    :sessions => 'sessions', 
    :confirmations => 'confirmations' 
} do
  match 'confirmations/unconfirmed' => 'confirmations#unconfirmed', :as => :unconfirmed
  match 'confirmations/send_advisor_confirmation/:id' => 'confirmations#unregistered_advisor_confirmation', :as => :send_advisor_confirmation
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: I have not worked with the native Devise + OmniAuth integration but I can attest that the tutorials at http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2 do work. They do not use Devise's built in integration however. I've used those tutorials in my own Facebook connected web app and it worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I forgot to put the following into `env.rb`

```
# features/support/env.rb
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

For more information read about the testing [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing).

Comment: Thanks a lot, even today in 2020, this answer helped me get on the right path for Omniauth testing (with Auth0).

Comment: For more informations about Omniauth testing : https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing